# Help convert console command to right-click command

Tags: 10.04, gnome, command-line, scripts

I use this console command to automatically send all files in some directory to the JAR file, catch the output of that JAR file and finally create new files from the output. Here is the command

```
for i in `find . -type f -name '*xml'`; do java -jar "~/grabbertty.jar" $i > $i.txt; done
```

Now, I know how to make nautilus-script which will be called via RightClick->Scripts.

What I **do not know** is how to convert this command to say "convert all files in **currently selected** directory". Currently selected directory is a directory where I right click.

Anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you, comment if something weird comes up

```
#! /bin/bash
base="`echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI | cut -d'/' -f3- | sed 's/%20/ /g'`"
if [ -z "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" ]; then
     dir="$base"
else
     while [ ! -z "$1" -a ! -d "$base/$1" ]; do shift; done
     dir="$base/$1"
fi

for i in `find "$dir" -type f -name '*xml'`; do java -jar "~/grabbertty.jar" $i > $i.txt; done
```

When you right click on a folder it should apply your `find` inside that folder, if you are not clicking on a folder it should apply your `find` inside the current folder.

Save it in your `"$HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/<nameofthescript>.sh` and make it executable with `chmod 755 <nameofthescript>.sh`.

Comment: Did all this, it appears among my other nautilus scripts, but it does not do anything. The original file is still unprocessed and no new file is created. As I cannot start this script from the shell, I cannot post any error message. Any suggestion?

Comment: Shame on me, miss copied your part (the important one!!!) so it was not working, its fixed.

Comment: If you want that the `i$.txt` files are created in the same directory as the original xml file instead of '**> $i.txt; done**' use '**> "$dir/$i.txt; done**' on the last line. Use the check to mark the question as answered if this fits your needs, regards.

Comment: Hi, it still does not work. I have tried both $i.txt and $dir/$i.txt and it does not work. all I got was that the empty file named Check.txt was generated in the same dir.

Comment: what happens if you to to a folder that contains the xml files and type `java -jar "~/grabbertty.jar" nameofoneofthefiles > test.txt`, replace <nameofoneofthefiles> with one of your xlm.

Comment: do you get any faults with that? is your test.txt the output you expected?

Comment: if I enter this command in the console, the grabber app will take XML content from a file, parse it and it will produce another TXT file with parsed content. I do not get any fault but total silence. The desired output is the TXT file like test.xml.